# How can I render a variable properly without confusing the Razor engine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I am trying to render CSS using the Razor view engine (yes, I know it was designed for xml-style languages).

My template looks like:

```
#@Model.ID {
    top: @Model.Toppx;
    left: @Model.Leftpx;
}
```

Of course this fails because `Toppx` and `Leftpx` arent properties of the model, `Top` and `Left` are. I cant put a space (eg `@Model.Top px;`) because while this works from a templating perspective, its invalid CSS and Firefox ignores it.

Other templating languages (Freemarker, Velocity) would support it like: `${Model.Top}px;` and even the usual ASP.NET view engine supports it like: `<%=Model.Top%>px;`

How can I get this behaviour in Razor? I tried:
`@:<text>@Model.Top</text>px` but that wouldnt compile.

I also tried: `@Model.Top@:px;` but that didnt work either.

Note: I am using the standalone Razor (found at http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) with Mono 2.10

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try explicitly expressing the code block with brackets:

```
#@(Model.ID) {
    top: @(Model.Top)px;
    left: @(Model.Left)px;
}
```